# Networkx - test null models against real modularity scores

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using the following function in order to get a modularity score for a given graph:

```
import networkx as nx

def modularity_score(graph):
    return nx_comm.modularity(graph, nx_comm.label_propagation_communities(graph))
```

Let's say my graph has 1858 nodes and it returns 0.7278 as my score.

---

Now I've learned that null models can help identify network properties that are different from what is expected based on the null hypothesis that networks are mostly random.

So which `Networkx` method can I use to compare my observed modularity score against and how do I calculate the test significance?

Using random graph with the same number of nodes?